# How to make each letter in text a different random color in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make every letter in a small line of text a different random color. I can only seem to make it do this when I use .hover, but I want it to do the action straight away (once the page loads). Please help. I would also like to know if anyone knows how to just set different colors on each letter (set colors) with css or Javascript because when I tried to do it in that way, it wouldnt allow me call a function on the same div/id (i tried to arch the text). Thank you.

THIS IS MY CODE

```
var colours = ["#000000", "#FF0000", "#990066", "#FF9966", "#996666", "#00FF00", "#CC9933"], 
    idx;

$("#arch").hover(function(){
    var div = $(this); 
    var chars = div.text().split('');
    div.html('');     
    for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        var span = $('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css("color", colours[idx])
        div.append(span);
    }

}, function() {
    $(this).find('span').css("color","#FF0000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var colours = ["#000000", "#FF0000", "#990066", "#FF9966", "#996666", "#00FF00", "#CC9933"], 
    idx;

$(function() {
    var div = $('#arch'); 
    var chars = div.text().split('');
    div.html('');     
    for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        var span = $('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css("color", colours[idx]);
        div.append(span);
    }
});
```

Works for me. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Eeg/)

You have to make sure the DOM is loaded before doing any jQuery stuff on it.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Try (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('#arch'); 
    var chars = div.text().split('');
    div.html('');     
    for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        var span = $('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css("color", colours[idx])
        div.append(span);
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to wait for the DOM to load so that there's a div to find when you call `$('#arch')`!

I'm not sure what you mean by "tried to arch the text".

Comment: I am trying to arch/curve the text, but when I try to do this with the random color thing, it does not arch the text.

CODE ->

 $("#arch").arctext({radius: 300})
 
 var colours = ["#000000", "#FF0000", "#990066", "#FF9966", "#996666", "#00FF00", "#CC9933"], 
    idx;

 $(function() {
    var div = $('#arch'); 
    var chars = div.text().split('');
    div.html('');     
    for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
        var span = $('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css("color", colours[idx]);
        div.append(span);
    }
});