# How to make multiple links function with different CSS-Styles?

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors, href

I am having trouble creating a link (`a href`) where certain characters show up in different colors but function as one link!

I tried to think creative and came up with the following codes.

*HTML:*

```
<a href="#" class="char1"> T </a>
<a href="#" class="char2"> E </a>
<a href="#" class="char3"> S </a>
<a href="#" class="char4"> T </a>
```

*CSS:*

```css
a.char1:link {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char1:visited {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char1:active {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char1:hover {color:blue; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a.char2:link {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char2:visited {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char2:active {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char2:hover {color:red; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a.char3:link {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char3:visited {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char3:active {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char3:link {color:green; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a.char4:link {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char4:visited {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char4:active {color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a.char4:hover {color:yellow; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
```

But then of course they won't function as a single link...

So again to simplify my question I want to create `a href` where all 'four' characters *(T, E, S, T)* show in diffrent colors when being hovered *(a.char:hover)*.

*"despite the fact only one character is hovered in this case"*

***thanks in advance!***

Comment: Use a single link which contains multiple `span` elements each with a separate character / styles

Comment: You could put each letter in a span like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azYdoE

Comment: you can have random colors too using some JS code -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228961/how-to-make-each-letter-in-text-a-different-random-color-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Like so--put the text into spans within the anchor tag:

```css
 body {
   background-color: #656565;
 }
 a:link .char1 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:visited .char1 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:active .char1 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:hover .char1 {
   color: blue;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:link .char2 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:visited .char2 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:active .char2 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:hover .char2 {
   color: red;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:link .char3 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:visited .char3 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:active .char3 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:link .char3 {
   color: green;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:link .char4 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:visited .char4 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:active .char4 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:hover .char4 {
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="char1">T</span>
  <span class="char2">E</span>
  <span class="char3">S</span>
  <span class="char4">T</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply helped me allot!

Answer (score 0):

you have to give hover for char 3 also.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#">
<span class="char1">T</span>
<span class="char2">E</span>
<span class="char3">S</span>
<span class="char4">T</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:link  .char1 .char2 .char3 .char4
{color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a:visited .char1 .char2 .char3 .char4
{color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a:active .char1 .char2 .char3 .char4
{color:#fff; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}

a:hover .char1 {color:blue; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover .char2 {color:red; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover  .char3{color:green; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover  .char4{color:yellow; font-size:13pt; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply helped me allot!